# Capture the new data in in file and write to Bigquery

Tags: function, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am new to GCP and need help to setup a system for this scenario .

There is a file in GCS and it gets written by an application program (for example log ) .
I need to capture every new record that is written in this file , then process the record by writing some logic  for some transformation in the data  and finally write it into a bigquery table .

I am thinking about this approach :

1. event trigger on Google storage for the file
2. write into pub/sub
3. apply google cloud function
4. subscribe into bigquery

I am not sure if this approach is optimal and right for this use case .
Please suggest .

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on your requirements. Here are some options:

#### 1

Is it appropriate to simply mount this file as an external table [like this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage#create_a_permanent_external_table)?

One example from those docs:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset.sales (
  Region STRING,
  Quarter STRING,
  Total_Sales INT64
) OPTIONS (
    format = 'CSV',
    uris = ['gs://mybucket/sales.csv'],
    skip_leading_rows = 1);
```

If your desired transformation can be expressed in SQL, this may be sufficient: you could define a SQL View that enacts the transformation but which will always query the most up-to-date version of the data. However, queries may turn out to be a little slow with this setup.

#### 2

How up-to-date does your BigQuery table have to be? Real-time accuracy is often not needed, in which case a batch load job on a schedule may be most appropriate. There's a nice built in system for this approach, [the BigQuery Data Transfer service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-storage-transfer), which you could use to sync the BigQuery table as often as every fifteen minutes.

Unlike with an external table, you could create a *materialized* view for your transformation, ensuring good performance with a guarantee that the data won't be more than 15 minutes out of data in the most regularly scheduled case.

#### 3

Okay, you need real time availability *and* good performance/your transformation is too complex to express with SQL? For this, your proposal looks okay, but it has quite a few moving parts, and there will certainly be *some* latency in the system. In this scenario you're likely better off following GCP's preferred route [of using the Dataflow service](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#text-files-on-cloud-storage-to-bigquery-stream). The link there is to the template they provide for streaming files from GCS into BigQuery, with a transformation of your choosing applied via a function.

#### 4

There is one other case I didn't deal with, which is where you *don't* need real-time data but the transformation is complex and can't be expressed with SQL. In this case I would probably suggest a batch job run on a simple schedule (using a GCS client library and a BigQuery client library in the language of your choice).

There are many, many ways to do this sort of thing, and unless you are working on a completely greenfield project you almost certainly have one you could use. But I will remark that GCP has recently created the ability to [use Cloud Scheduler to execute Cloud Run Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs-on-schedule), which may be easiest if you don't already have a way to do this.

---

None of this is to say your approach won't work - you can definitely trigger a cloud function directly based on a change in a GCP bucket, and so you could write a function to perform the ELT process every time. It's not a bad all-round approach, but I have aimed to give you some examples that are either simpler or more performant, covering a variety of possible requirements.